# Pulseaudio Virtual Sink to Virtual Source

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio

I am trying to create both a virtual speaker and a virtual microphone to direct the output from one software to the input of another software, but I am running in dead ends trying to figure out how to use PulseAudio in such a way, most posts I have found are not helping me at all with my problem. Can someone please help me?

Basically:

Virtual Speaker ---> Virtual Microphone

Comment: And if using the associated `.monitor` source is not enough, see the many answers on this site that include "null sink" (this is your "virtual speaker").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulseaudio automatically creates a monitor source for any audio playback sink

on my system Pulseaudio card **Profile** is set to **Analog Stereo Output** instead of **Analog Stereo Duplex** for input+output. checking available sinks with 'pactl list short sinks' responds

```
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_04_06.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s32le 2ch 48000Hz   IDLE
```

and for 'pactl list short sources'

```
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_04_06.0.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s32le 2ch 48000Hz   IDLE
```

audio playing to alsa_output.pci-0000_04_06.0.analog-stereo can be recorded from alsa_output.pci-0000_04_06.0.analog-stereo.monitor

in Pulseaudio Volume Control GUI, monitor sources are not visible as input devices by default in `pulseaudio -t 4` 
dropdown menu at bottom right of window '**Show**' is usually set to show only '**Hardware input devices**' change this to '**All input devices**' to make monitor sources visible

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a GUI on that machine. I did create the sources for the sink monitors, but it seems that the sources I bound uppon them are not using ALSA. Do you know how I can create a ALSA source on that monitor from the console?